# Jenkins hide build parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I currently have Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy enabled.  I would like to hide certain build parameters from some users when they run a job.  Is there a Jenkins plugin available for that?

I saw this was asked in 2014 and after 4 years I am hoping that something was created.  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a plugin called "Mask Passwords Plugin".

After installation goto: manage jenkins > configure system and select parameters to hide:
[image]